# Service crash without any log in Huawei p8 device

Tags: android, service, android-audiorecord

I am developing an audio recording application. It's just working fine in most of the devices but in `Huawei p8(lite)` and `Samsung S7`.

In those device(`p8 specially`) `service stopped and restart` (because of `sticky` service). Also foreground activity restarted but doesn't `crash or close`. Problem is that, there is no `logcat message` about the crash. I tried to run `service` in `foreground` but no luck. I found the following log before and after crash.

Service start from `MainActivity` and it crash(after 5-10 minutes) when `RecordingActivity` is in foreground.

```
10-27 22:15:18.173: D/hw_netstat(3089): total/11828/12216,com.example.recorder/11828/12216
10-27 22:15:18.174: E/HwCHRWebMonitor(3089): getFileResult throw exceptionjava.io.FileNotFoundException: proc/net/wifi_network_stat: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
10-27 22:15:18.182: D/WifiHW(3089): wifi_command: g_p2p_enabled=0,command=IFNAME=wlan0 SIGNAL_POLL,pthread_mutex_lock begin.
10-27 22:15:18.182: D/WifiHW(3089): wifi_send_command: cmd:'IFNAME=wlan0 SIGNAL_POLL'
10-27 22:15:18.182: D/WifiHW(3089): wifi_send_command enter, cmd=IFNAME=wlan0 SIGNAL_POLL,g_p2p_enabled=0
10-27 22:15:18.183: D/wpa_supplicant(3907): wlan0: Control interface command 'SIGNAL_POLL'
10-27 22:15:18.183: D/WifiHW(3089): wpa_ctrl_request ret=0,reply_len=48
10-27 22:15:18.183: D/WifiHW(3089): wpa_ctrl_request reply=RSSI=-55
10-27 22:15:18.183: D/WifiHW(3089): LINKSPEED=72
10-27 22:15:18.183: D/WifiHW(3089): NOISE=9999
10-27 22:15:18.183: D/WifiHW(3089): FREQUENCY=2422
10-27 22:15:18.183: D/WifiHW(3089): 0��l
10-27 22:15:18.183: D/WifiHW(3089): wifi_command: g_p2p_enabled=0,command=IFNAME=wlan0 SIGNAL_POLL pthread_mutex_unlock ok.
10-27 22:15:18.184: E/WifiConfigStore(3089): updateConfiguration freq=2422 BSSID=e8:de:27:ea:1a:96 RSSI=-54 "TP-LINK_SAHA"WPA_PSK
10-27 22:15:18.184: D/WifiHW(3089): wifi_command: g_p2p_enabled=0,command=IFNAME=wlan0 PKTCNT_POLL,pthread_mutex_lock begin.
10-27 22:15:18.184: D/WifiHW(3089): wifi_send_command: cmd:'IFNAME=wlan0 PKTCNT_POLL'
10-27 22:15:18.184: D/WifiHW(3089): wifi_send_command enter, cmd=IFNAME=wlan0 PKTCNT_POLL,g_p2p_enabled=0
10-27 22:15:18.184: D/wpa_supplicant(3907): wlan0: Control interface command 'PKTCNT_POLL'
10-27 22:15:18.184: D/WifiHW(3089): wpa_ctrl_request ret=0,reply_len=36
10-27 22:15:18.184: D/WifiHW(3089): wpa_ctrl_request reply=TXGOOD=131285
10-27 22:15:18.184: D/WifiHW(3089): TXBAD=0
10-27 22:15:18.184: D/WifiHW(3089): RXGOOD=212440
10-27 22:15:18.184: D/WifiHW(3089): 
10-27 22:15:18.184: D/WifiHW(3089): wifi_command: g_p2p_enabled=0,command=IFNAME=wlan0 PKTCNT_POLL pthread_mutex_unlock ok.
10-27 22:15:18.185: D/HuaweiWifiWatchdogStateMachine(3089): LM mrssi=-55
10-27 22:15:18.372: I/ActivityManager(3089): Process com.example.recorder (pid 26678) has died
10-27 22:15:18.374: W/ActivityManager(3089): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.example.recorder/com.example.MyService in 1000ms
10-27 22:15:18.374: I/WindowState(3089): WIN DEATH: Window{c073671 u0 com.example.recorder/com.example.recorder.RecordingActivity}
10-27 22:15:18.374: D/GraphicsStats(3089): Buffer count: 5
10-27 22:15:18.375: D/Sensors(3089): sensors_poll_context_t->activate(handle: 4, enabled: 0)
10-27 22:15:18.376: D/Sensors(3089): ProximitySensor: fd (220 ),flags(0), mEnabled(1),input_sys_path (/sys/class/sensors/ps_sensor/enable)
10-27 22:15:18.376: W/InputDispatcher(3089): channel '1393541 com.example.recorder/com.example.recorder.MainActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
10-27 22:15:18.376: E/InputDispatcher(3089): channel '1393541 com.example.recorder/com.example.recorder.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
10-27 22:15:18.378: E/HsmCoreServiceImpl(3089): onTransact in code is: 102
10-27 22:15:18.379: I/MediaProcessHandler(3089): processOp opType: 1, uid: 10100, pid: 26678
10-27 22:15:18.382: I/WindowState(3089): WIN DEATH: Window{1393541 u0 com.example.recorder/com.example.recorder.MainActivity}
10-27 22:15:18.382: W/InputDispatcher(3089): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '1393541 com.example.recorder/com.example.recorder.MainActivity (server)'
10-27 22:15:18.388: I/APM::AudioPolicyManager(2627): stopInput() input 131
10-27 22:15:18.394: I/audio_hw_primary(2627): do_in_standby standby: 0, in_device: 4
10-27 22:15:18.398: I/ActivityManager(3089): Start proc 27173:com.example.recorder/u0a100 for activity com.example.recorder/.RecordingActivity
10-27 22:15:18.401: I/art(27173): Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
10-27 22:15:18.413: I/audio_hw_primary(2627): select_devices++ mode[0]
10-27 22:15:18.414: I/audio_hw_primary(2627): output_device_id is 1, output_route is media-earpiece;input_source_id is 0, input_route is null.
```

Comment: maybe doze mode kill your app and then service recreated. 
Try request add app to ignore doze mode

Answer (score 0):

Actually log records like this:

```
10-27 22:15:18.374: W/ActivityManager(3089): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.example.recorder/com.example.MyService in 1000ms
```

don't mean that some `Service` has actually crashed because of some code defect or fatal error. It simply means that process, that hosts this service, has died. And nothing more. Actual reasons may differ: it may be unhandled java exception (anywhere in process, not only in `Service` code), some native crash or process was simply killed by the system for any reason but usually for resource reclamation.

So if you see such message - don't be upset. If there are no messages about actual crash - there was no crash.

P.S. If you are interested - look at [these](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/froyo-release/services/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityManagerService.java#11163) lines. This is a place where that confusing message is printed.

Comment: I can understand service was crashed but there is no crash log for java or native section. Most important part, it's running in most of the device. Is there any tools available in android like gdb. So it will give stack trace when application crash. I need to find out where it's crashing.

Comment: @shantanu [`ndk-gdb`](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/ndk-gdb.html) may help you.